# view and primary link

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I have a primary link "accommodation", then i have created a view , called "listing", and set that listing path to "accommodation".

but when i access url myurl/accommodation , the view was not show up. but default content of primary link "accommodation" showed up.

how can i make myurl/accommodation to show my "listing" view.

thanks

Comment: What is the path defined for your primary link 'accommodation'? Also, what is the 'default' content that shows up?

Comment: sorry for later , i just deleted that 'accommodation' in primay link, and changed view 'accommodation' menu path to primary link. in view , we can set view as primary link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a stupid question but have you given drupal views the page view argument or whatever it needs?